# bash script - "Rscript: command not found" error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, r

I have the following bash script trying to run it in Linux but I receive an error message that `line 31: Rscript: command not found`. Can you please give me an advice if where I am wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N garunsmodel
#PBS -l mem=10g
#PBS -l walltime=02:00:00
#PBS -A improvingherds
#PBS -m ae


nodeDir=`mktemp -d /tmp/phuong.XXXXX`

cp -r /group/dairy/phuongho/garuns $nodeDir

cd $nodeDir

cd garuns
module load gcc vle // this is to load vle platform
rm -rf out
mkdir out

#In garuns.vpz. The output file path has to be changed.
#to an absolute path that's available on the node the script is running.

XXX=`pwd`
sed -i "s|/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns/out|$XXX/out/|" exp/garuns.vpz
Rscript  R/repetability.R

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
mkdir "/group/dairy/phuongho/job.$DATE"

cp -r out  "/group/dairy/phuongho/job.$DATE"
```

When I tried to access manually to `tmp/phuong.XXXXX/garuns` then run R, it worked just fine.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant /usr/bin/Rscript is provided by package r-base-core in Ubuntu, I believe

Comment: the file named: repetability.R contain all R commands needed to run the model garuns above. So, I am not sure if we have to specify anything. The repetability.R lives in: /garuns/R/repetability.R 
Thanks

Comment: Should also probably be `Rscript ~/R/repetability.R`?

Answer (score 3):

If R has already been installed, it could be that the `PATH` variable picks up the wrong `RScript`? Check with `which RScript`

In this case try

`export PATH=/path/to/alternate/r/bin:$PATH`

Or try brute-forcing by giving the absolute path when referencing `RScript`, e.g.

`~/R-3.2.5_patched/bin/RScript/R/repetability.R`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install R

For example on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

Then the `Rscript` command will be recognized at the command line.

I did this and it worked but be aware that the install was pretty massive with hundreds of dependencies installed.  Took a few minutes to install.

Comment: hi Michael, in this case R has been already installed.

Comment: hmmm, when I put it in a file it recognizes the command, e.g. `$ cat x.sh
Rscript x.R
$ ./x.sh 
Fatal error: cannot open file 'x.R': No such file or directory
` - can't open file but Rscript command itself was recognized.

Comment: My actual situation is that, I have a model called garuns with all source codes are written in the folder garuns above. To run this, we designed an Rscript which contain command for running garuns model as well as some calculations from the output.
On my local directory, I can easily run this model by cd to garuns, then run: Rscript R/repetability.R (this works perfectly).

Comment: However, I now want to not run this on my local directory but on the cluster of our faculty. As you can see from the code above:
I first need to copy on garuns folder to a tmp folder on the computer node, then from there I cd to garuns, then start running R as when I am on local directory. On cluster, the IT guys have installed R, as well as the vle package that I need. So I can not figure out what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a script that is submitted to a compute cluster through something like SLURM.  You should talk to your system's administrator and ask whether R is installed on the cluster and if so, how to enable access to it in your script.

On the clusters I have access to, some software will need to be loaded with a `module load somesoftware/version` command, which updates/sets the environment variables needed to run the software.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by replacing `Rscript` in my bash script with `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` (or wherever your Rscript is located - do `which Rscript` to find out).  Explicitly adding it to my PATH as suggested in other answers made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message but for a different reason. Posting it here as people will land here like I did too.

Check your first line is `#!/bin/bash` (which isn't your problem) rather than `#!/bin/sh`, else some commands like `module load <>` won't run.